# How to manage colour in After Effects to get precisely a desired colour in h264 output

Tags: after-effects, h.264, color, colorspace

I am working on a video for the web only.
It is going to be on a webpage (never on broadcast), delivered as an h264 file.
The web page background is hex code FFF1E5 (RGB 255, 241, 229).
My background colour in After Effects is a solid with colour FFF1E5.
How do I generate an h264 video file with a background *precisely* this colour.
Not a little bit off. Exactly this colour.
Because I've tried adjusting colour Working Space in Project Settings until I'm 0000FF in the face...

The link supplied in the highest rated answer [in this similar question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10305/upon-export-in-premiere-pro-colors-lose-saturation-when-previewing-in-quicktime/10336#10336) is broken.

My usual workflow is:

export as ProRes 422 (or 4444 - same problem) from After Effects CC2020

Convert to h264 in Media Encoder CC2020

[image: screengrab]

Comment: In which colorspace are you working? Just an idea: Have you ticked the checkbox "Preserve RGB" under the color-management tab in the Output Module?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't tried that... Wish it was all in one place! But it's still not working...  Just tried : project setttings = 8 bit, no working space, assume working gamma = sRGB. In the output module I chose ProRes 4444, and Colour Management = preserve RGB. Converted to h264 in Media Encoder, and opened the mp4 in Chrome.  It's still wrong!

Comment: Huh that is strange. Have you tried converting the 4444 to h264 using ffmpeg or handbrake? I'm assuming the error might be in the conversion through the media-encoder.

Comment: Just tried doing the h264 conversion in Handbrake using the technique in previous comment - same issue

Comment: That's so very strange... I'll do some googling around and ask at my workplace. Maybe someone knows how to deal with this issue. Until then, good luck!

Comment: Appreciate it! It's an odd one, but should be easy to replicate the fault I hope

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot use hyperlinks in comments, here is the gist of my research:

[This answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T9NL.jpg) on a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/editors/comments/3446nr/has_anyone_solved_the_color_shift_when_rendering/) suggests, that the reason for the color-shift is the way illegal and legal colors are handled. So maybe the "broadcast colors" effect can help limit the color-range to the legal range? I'd recommend giving that a quick shot.

If that doesn't work, it should certainly do the trick to use Resolve and select video-levels instead of data-levels and encode the 4444 to h264 from there.
Please do report back and good luck!